# Android OpenCV - How can i read video files with using jni?

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, native

I am developing an application using Android Opencv.

This app, which I am developing, offers two operations.

- The frame read from the camera is passed to Jni using native function
  Mat.getNativeObjAddr (), and the new image is returned through
  javaCameraView's onCameraFrame() function
- It reads a video clip inside Storage, processes each frame the same
  as # 1, and returns the resulting image via the onCameraFrame()
  function.

First,function is implemented as simple as the following and works normally:

```
   @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
    {
        if(inputFrame!=null){
                Detect(inputFrame.rgba().getNativeObjAddr(), boardImage.getNativeObjAddr());
            }
            return boardImage;
        }
    }
```

However, the problem occurred in the second operation.
 As far as I know, the files inside Java Storage are not readable by jni.

I already tried **FFmpegMediaPlayer** or **MediaMetadataRetriever** through Google search. However, the **getFrameAtTime** () function provided by this MetadataRetriever took an average of 170ms when grabbing a bitmap to a specific frame of 1920 * 1080 image. What I have to develop is to show the video results in real time at 30 fps. In # 1, the native function Detect () takes about 2ms to process one frame.

For these reasons, I want to do this.

java sends a video's path (eg : /storage/emulated/0/download/video.mp4) to jni, and native functions process the video one frame at a time, and display the result image on 'onCameraFrame'.

Is there a proper way? I look forward to your reply. Thank you!

Comment: If you ask, it is proper way or not, yes. You can work in native side, with pathname. And it will reduce your processes time multiply times.

Comment: Or you need solution of how to send pathname to jni side?

Comment: @JavadKhan Oh, really? Is it possible to pass the video pathname to jni and read from jni frame by frame? If that is possible, and you have the solution, I'd like to receive it with my e-mail:
sso99111@gmail.com